# Package <package name> has no installation candidate

Tags: apt

I want to install some applications but for any installation command it says that this package `has no installation candidate`. I can't even run `sudo apt-get update`.

```
cookie98@cookie98**:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for cookie98: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package software-properties-common is not available, but is 
  referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is
 only available from another source

E: Package 'software-properties-common' has no installation candidate
```

`

Comment: If you cannot run `sudo apt-get update` your system is seriously ill or there is no connection to the internet. Which version of Ubuntu are you running (for example 16.04 LTS? How did you install it? Did you upgrade it? What is the output of the following command: `uname -a`

Comment: ubuntu 17.10, I install it on a partition of hard-drive of 150 Gb. I upgrade but **apt-get upgrade** not working.

Comment: "not working" is a bit vague. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: 1. What do you mean by 'I upgrade'. Did you upgrade the release from 17.04 to 17.10? Or do you mean that `sudo apt-get upgrade` did not work? 2. I agree with@user535733, please give us the complete output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` -- edit the original question and indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code'.

Comment: Please give us all the error output of `apt-get update` as edit of your question

Comment: Did you changed `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ? Did you tried to switch to other mirror with `software-properties-gtk`?

Answer (score 0):

When I had the "no installation candidate" issue (but with a different installation), the problem was with my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. It might help to check yours

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```